# Visual Studio Extensions SDK - can we access FTP functions?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to build a Visual Studio extension (using VS 2017 Community).

Visual Studio already comes with the ability to publish files via FTP to a remote server (for website projects); so obviously, there must be some sort of FTP library (or class) within Visual Studio.

**My Question:**

Does anyone know if there is an FTP class within the Visual Studio SDK that allows developers to publish files via FTP?  Currently, I have not found anything within the Visual Studio Extensions [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/inside-the-visual-studio-sdk) -- but I thought I should ask those who may be in the know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio uses a licensed copy of Rebex FTP/SSL client library,

https://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/default.aspx

which can be found in path such as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Rebex.Net.Ftp.dll`

Whether you can consume that library in your extension is not clear. So if you do want to be freely working on your extension, use an open source FTP library or the .NET Framework built-in classes might be a better option.

Comment: Hi Lex - thanks, and yes it appears VS is using the Rebex library.  Unfortunately, I have not found any service that exposes any FTP functions within VS, so it looks like I'll end up using the .Net built in FTP classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a couple:
For FTPS(Small use case) i used limilabs:
https://www.limilabs.com/ftp (Requires payment, simple ftp as well)

For built in FTP, i programmed using sockets:
System.Net.Sockets.Socket
System.Net.IPEndPoint

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx

The code is a bit obtuse but it works, i found a similar program tutorial for you:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35902-create-an-ftp-class-library-in-c%23/

Comment: Thank-you for your reply.  But I am asking if an EXISTING FTP class or API is available within the Visual Studio Extensions SDK -- I was hoping to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @bdcoder have you checked .net built-in FTP classes? For example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes - thank-you, I am well aware of the .Net classes -- I was hoping to use a service (FTP) that already exists within Visual Studio -- trouble is, it doesn't look like the FTP service is exposed in the SDK -- at least, I have not been able to find any reference.